# Dynamic affinity on Linux

Tags: linux, process, affinity

Is there a way to get dynamic the core CPU that is not used by any process?

I want to use the [taskset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity#Specific_operating_systems) command or any other Linux command to get a "free" CPU that my processes are not running on.

A core command from Linux or else use a script.

Comment: How is this on-topic?

Comment: *[Processor affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity#Specific_operating_systems)*